# Is this limit proof right?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> If $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a}$ then $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\alpha a_n=\alpha a}$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\alpha \neq 0$. Then for all $(\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}>0)(\exists n(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N})$ so that for all $n>n(\epsilon)$ we have $|a_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}$.

Take $n(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}$. Now,

$|\alpha a_n - \alpha a|=|\alpha||a_n-a|<|\alpha|\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}=\epsilon$.

Comment: It is alright although is infrequent to say for all $\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$.

Comment: You did not cover the case $\alpha =0$ although it's an obvious case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. Why did you take $n(\epsilon)=\frac\epsilon{|\alpha|}$, and where was that used? It should be the same $n(\epsilon)$ that was used in the first limit. It should be more along the lines of:

For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n(\epsilon)>0$ such that if $n>n(\epsilon)$, then $|a_n-a|<\frac\epsilon{|\alpha|}$, and therefore,

$$|\alpha a_n-\alpha a|=|\alpha||a_n-a|<|\alpha|\frac\epsilon{|\alpha|}=\epsilon.$$